# Showing $\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\int_I|f|^p\right)^{1/p} = \max|f|$, where $I$ is a generalized rectangle

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $I$ be a generalized rectangle and let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\int_I|f|^p\right)^{1/p} = \max|f|$$

I found it straightforward to show that these integrals in the limit sequence are properly defined and I showed the LHS $\leq$ RHS by using the definition of the integral using partitions. I am confused about the approach to showing that RHS $\leq$ LHS to give equality.

Thanks for any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume the continuity of $f$ or else the statement is not true since you wrote $\max|f|$ instead of $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$.

Assume also that $\max|f|>0$ and choose an $0<\epsilon<\max|f|$.

Then there exists an $x_{0}$ such that $\max|f|-\epsilon<|f(x_{0})|$. The continuity implies that $\max|f|-\epsilon<|f(x)|$ for a rectangle $J\subseteq I$ that containing $x_{0}$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{J}(\max|f|-\epsilon_{0})^{p}\right)^{1/p}\leq\left(\int_{J}|f(x)|^{p}\right)^{1/p}\leq\left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^{p}\right)^{1/p},
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
(\max|f|-\epsilon)|J|^{1/p}\leq\left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^{p}\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align*}
Taking $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ we get
\begin{align*}
(\max|f|)|J|^{1/p}\leq\left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^{p}\right)^{1/p}\leq(\max|f|)|I|^{1/p}.
\end{align*}
Now using Squeeze Theorem to conclude the result.

Comment: Oh good catch; yes f is meant to be continuous. Thank you for the response. Am I correct in observing that the second line of your argument uses the definition of the integral in terms of sums of partitions?

Comment: I didn't quite use the sums of partitions. Anyway, which you referred to exactly?

Comment: I'm asking specifically about going from $(∫_J(\max|f|−ϵ_0)^p)^{1/p}$ to $(\max|f|−ϵ)|J|^{1/p}$. How does this work?

Comment: Oh that is nothing to do with partition. Note that $\max|f|-\epsilon$ is just a constant. You are integrating with a constant, so what left is the only area of the domain.